# Mobile App - Best Approach to switch between Firebase Projects in Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are creating a mobile app that will use Firebase Authentication.
This app is an app used for enterprise customers who subscribed for the service.
Our plan in terms of architecture is:
  - have just one app client for all customers
  - create a Firebase project for each customer

In this context, what could be a best approach for app define which Firebase Project login ?
Do someone has experience with Firebase in Multi tenant environment ?

Regards,

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but I don't see the benefit of having multiple customer-specific projects. In Firebase, you can certainly design a document/collection which should be specific to each of your customer, and build off from that. Having multiple projects would mean that you are managing multiple data stores, as well as defining multiple authentication mechanisms, as well as cloud functions which you are bound to use at some point of your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The idea is to segregate the customer data "physically" at Google. How this is an app for Corporate communication like an Email Server we are trying to be prepared in case of legal request for customer data, like labor process or other situation we need to extract the data. Make sense ?

Comment: The *customer* data could still be technically separated (through collections/documents) in Firebase rather than separating them initially. Perhaps you could look at the functionality of separating the specific customer data if there is an actual request in place. Managing multiple database / firestore instances would be quite complex in the long run.

Comment: Just to add further, I have seen an APP before where the user has to supply a different code, where the central database / firestore instance for login will associate the code with a different db instance that is supplied back to the customer. The customer after the login portion is then directed to peruse that db instance for all other transactions.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks a lot for time to contribute

Comment: Firebase is not well suited for multi-tenant apps. However, if you want to use a single app backed by a single Firebase and each customer has it's own node with that Firebase, it could be done noting you would also have a shared user authentication but that could be managed. But then you're suggesting having a different Firebase project for each customer which is then not multi-tenant since each project only has one customer. So... the question is a bit confusing. Note that single-tenant is generally defined as each customer has their own independent database which would be the case.